# Dynamic Database Connections based on User in Loopback

Tags: mysql, node.js, loopbackjs

I am evaluating Loopback for a new platform our company is building. I setup a test project and despite the learning curve, am absolutely loving the Loopback framework. One deal breaker I cannot seem to figure out is how to dynamically connect to a database on request, based on the user and customer requesting the data.
Our legacy system has a database per customer, and per customer location (a customer with 3 locations would have 4 databases total) and there is no plan to migrate the data structure any time soon. This means when a request is made, we need to connect to that customers database, fetch data, then disconnect.
Any Loopback folks know if this is possible?

Comment: did you find solution if yes how please post you working sample

Answer (score 2):

Consider you have below in `datasources.json`

```
"db1": {
    "name": "db1",
    "host": "localhost",
    "database": "customers_one_db",
    "password": "",
    "user": "",
    "connector": "mysql"
  },
"db2": {
    "name": "db2",
    "host": "localhost",
    "database": "customers_two_db",
    "password": "",
    "user": "",
    "connector": "mysql"
  }
```

Create a middleware like this :

```
//middlewares.json
"inital:after": {
 ...
 "./middlewares/dsChanger": {}
 ...
}

//middlewares/dsChanger.js
var app = require('../server');
module.exports = function(options) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.headers.customerType === 'blah'){
      app.models.Customer.attachTo(app.datasources.db2);
    }else {
      app.models.Customer.attachTo(app.datasources.db1);
    }
    next();
  }
}
```

*Disclaimer: I didn't try this before*

**UPDATE**

For creating datasources in code you can do like :

```
var DataSource = require('loopback-datasource-juggler').DataSource;
var mysqlConnector = require('loopback-connector-mysql');

var ds1 = new DataSource(mysqlConnector, {
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'customers_one_db',
  username: '',
  password: ''
});
```

And don't forget to create another middlware and put it the last middleware phase, to `disconnect` the datasource.

```
ds1.disconnect(function(err, result){});
```

Comment: So the datasources.json is a non-starter because I am dealing with several thousand databases. However, it seems your solution would work well if I can create a new data source inline (without adding to the datasources.json file). Do you believe that would work?

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Ebrahim! I will try this out and mark the answer complete when it does (I am confident it will).

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani Why is the disconnect important? I tried to put it in routes:after, just to find out that this is never called by express.

Comment: @chris08002 If we create datasource manually so we need to disconnect it manually. But if the datasource is created by loopback (using datasource.json) we don't need to disconnect. Its lifecycle managed by loopback.